# upstart does not see my job

Tags: linux, ubuntu, upstart, ubuntu-12.10

in Ubuntu 12.10

```
user@xyz:~$ sudo initctl --version
initctl (upstart 1.5)
Copyright (C) 2012 Scott James Remnant, Canonical Ltd.

This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
user@xyz:~$ ls -l /etc/init/rs-comm.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 349 нояб. 15 03:22 /etc/init/rs-comm.conf
user@xyz:~$ sudo initctl reload-configuration
user@xyz:~$ sudo initctl start rs-comm
initctl: Unknown job: rs-comm
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your job probably contains invalid syntax, which means Upstart will not consider it. Try running the following as a normal user (**not** as root):

```
init-checkconf /etc/init/rs-comm.conf
```

Comment: `ERROR: failed to ask Upstart to check conf file`

Comment: it is ubuntu server w/o GUI. [here](http://pastebin.com/7aJ3uDA6) is output of
`init-checkconf -d /etc/init/rsyslog.conf`
Upstart does not reply over D-Bus

Comment: Solved. I have noticed in debug output of init-checkconf that it asks Upstart to write answer into file in `/tmp`. I looked there - here they are - several files pointing on error in my job file.  I have fixed that typo and now my job is seen by Upstart. There is still question why init-checkconf does not see Upstart answers.

Comment: @xdenser The problem with init-checkconf is most likely this issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/upstart/+bug/881885

Comment: I'm trying this in RHEL 6 and can't find any `init-checkconf` command to test the syntax.  I've run the same upstart job in Ubuntu without an error.  `yum info upstart` returns: `Installed Packages
Name       : upstart
Arch       : x86_64
Version    : 0.6.5
Release    : 12.el6_4.1
Size       : 550 k
Repo       : installed
From repo  : rhel-x86_64-server-6`  The job ends with `.conf` and the file permissions look okay.  Doing `sudo initctl list` shows all of the files in `/etc/init/` except the job in question.

Comment: A-ha!  `tail`ing `/var/log/messages` showed `Feb  5 17:06:24 da-host init: /etc/init/blah.conf:13: Unknown stanza`.  Progress!  Now I can debug.

Comment: In a headless environment: Use `export DISPLAY=:0`, then use the verbose/debug `-d` flag: `init-checkconf -d /etc/init/your-service.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

On RedHat v6.8 (and probably other versions and distros) upstart will not see the new job if the filename doesn't have a .conf extension.  For example, I just encountered this issue when I created an NGiNX upstart as `/etc/init/nginx`.  `initctl list | grep nginx` returned nothing.  `initctl status nginx` returned `initctl: Unkown job: nginx`.  So, I renamed the upstart job filename to `/etc/init/nginx.conf` and it immediately recognized it as a new upstart job.  I suspect this could affect a lot of people, so I thought I'd post it as a relevant answer.